# How to fit data of an excel file with curve fit?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I'm a beginner in python. I have an excel file. It has 4 columns. The first column is date, other columns are velocity (v), temperature (t), and pressure (p) respectively. This excel file contained data for one year. This a sample of my excel file.

```
Date        V      t     p
2016-01-01  0.01   2     7
2016-01-02  0.04   2.1   6.6
.
.
.
2016-12-30  0.07   4     5
```

I want to fit temperature and pressure to velocity by a linear equation.

`V = a*t+b*p+c`

I want to find a, b, and c by curve fitting Scipy package. I guess I should use a loop! This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import least_squares

df =pd.read_excel ('final-all-filters.xlsx')
x = df['Date']
V = df['V']
t = df['t']
p = df['p']
def model(a, b, c):
        return a*t+b*p+c

popt,pcov = curve_fit (model, t, p, V, maxfev = 10000)
plt.plot(t, p, V, label="Original Noised Data")
plt.plot(t, p, model(t, p, *popt), 'r-', label="Fitted Curve")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fit a model with two independent variables (t and c). You need to pass the xdata argument of model_fit as a array [t,p], and construct the model function such as the first argument is that array. Something like this:

```
def model(TP,a, b, c):
    t,p = TP
    return a*t+b*p+c

popt,pcov = curve_fit (model, [t, p], V, maxfev = 10000)
```

Maybe it is a good idea to insert the p0 argument also, a array with tree elements of a initial guess for a,b, and c.

And be aware that there is more than one solution for the a,b parameters. You may want to check the documentation for more information

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html